# Deleting a nested object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I delete a specific translation given the following serializer structure:

```
from rest_framework import serializers    
from .models import Category, Translation


class CategoryTranslationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Translation
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'language')


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    translation_set = CategoryTranslationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'parent', 'translation_set')
```

Comment: Do you mean deleting the class instance or an actual instance of the class?

Comment: @PrestonHager I mean deleting a single translation DB record.